# OAuth in Angular.js; redirect from page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flask

I am making a Flask app with an Angular front end. I have been trying to implement github login. On the flask side, I was able to authenticate users with `flask_oauthlib`. Going from the basic example, I was able to authenticate the user, save him to the db, and then return the json representing that user.

However, I am not sure how to work this into the angular front end. I have made it fairly hacky so far, relying on that they will be redirected back and using Jinja2 within the *base* template (the only `render_template` sent)

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated() %}
  <h3>Welcome back, {{ current_user.name }}!</h3>
{% else %}
  <a href="/login/github/">Login with Github</a>
{% endif %}
```

The user is not stored in my angular side of things anywhere. Clicking the link will go to a page showing the json representing the user, showing that it did properly authenticate.

Since this redirects away from the page, I am not sure how this is meant to be implemented in Angular.js. What would be the proper way to handle this?

Comment: You need to write AngularJS parts. Have a look here: http://beletsky.net/2013/11/simple-authentication-in-angular-dot-js-app.html

Comment: You might want to have a look at userapp.io as well.

Comment: this looks rather promising, given how small scale my app actually is. Thank you, sir